# What are the differences between CS 1.6 and CS:GO?

Tags: counter-strike, counter-strike-global-offensive

What are the differences between CS 1.6 and CS:GO? A simple bullet point comparison similar to [What are the differences between CS 1.6 and CS:S?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/76014/what-are-the-differences-between-counter-strike-1-6-and-cssource) would be nice.

Comment: The way you've worded this question makes it sound like you're asking for opinions and discussion.  The question you linked to just lists the differences; if you're looking for the same sort of thing, I'd recommend limiting the question to just, "What differences are there between CS:GO and X?"  Until then, I've voted to close.

Comment: I edited the question so that it is a comparison between CS:GO and CS 1.6. Then one could compare CS:GO and CS:S by looking at both questions.

Comment: Much better!  This is much more answerable than the original question.

Comment: After editing it I tried to flag it in order for an admin to see notice. Is that the way to inform an admin? If so, I believe I failed to flag, since it told me that I had 10 flags open today, even after I thought I had flagged it.

Comment: That is indeed correct.  Now we just need to be patient until it gets the number of people seeing it who agree it should be re-opened.

Comment: Similar to: http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/82047/what-are-the-differences-between-counter-strike-global-offensive-and-counter-st/82050

Comment: Maybe we should just close this one, since both of the other comparisons exist!

Comment: I think the original question was the most answerable and all-encompassing, actually.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, there are many differences attributed between CS1.6 and CS:GO.  The most important thing to note is the engine; it's improved dramatically over the past 9 years (CS1.6 was released in 2003, CS:GO in 2012).  Namely, CS1.6 uses the [GoldSrc](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GoldSrc) engine, which is a heavily modified Quake engine, and CS:Go uses the [Source](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Source_%28game_engine%29) engine.

Second, CS:GO features drastically balanced gamemodes and weapons.  Most notably, they completely changed the way Hostage missions worked previously in CS:S and CS1.6, and made it a lot more balanced for both sides.  Some new weapons were added, and most of other weapons got a huge balance update (default pistols get a buff that puts them up to standard to other pistols, deagle nerfed).

Along with that, CS:GO also features a matchmaking system extremely similar to that of TF2, but it forms games based on a "combat rank", which helps to put similar players of similar skills in the same games.

Some other features are a complete UI revitalization, a more informative and easy to use buy menu, and an extremely polished user-friendly tutorial. Some minor things are the removal of flashlights (some servers have it with plugins), as well as getting rid of pre-defined loadouts.

Also included now are "weapon" skins, cosmetic variants of stock weapons that have no effect on gameplay but can do things such as track kill counts, be named as something else, etc.

Comment: Self comment: I believe the animations have improved drastically from the orginial game; I abhorred the reload animations within both CS:S and CS1.6. CS:GO gave me the satisfaction I needed

Comment: With _The Arms Deal Update_ silenced weapons were added to _CS:GO_

Comment: + revamped grenade trajectories.